# Build a JSON array of objects in node JS

Tags: node.js, json

I would like to build a JSON structure as below

```
{
  "employee": {
    "hireDate": "01/01/2000",
    "serviceDate": "01/01/2000",
    "employeeDetails": [
      {
        "roleName": "Analyst",
        "beginDate": "01/01/2000",
        "endDate": "12/31/2001",
        "status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "roleName": "Developer",
        "beginDate": "01/01/2002",
        "endDate": "01/01/2021",
        "status": "Active"
      }
    ],
    "name": [
      {
        "firstName": "Jason",
        "lastName": "Washington"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm have individual objects information as seperate resultsets from DB2 SQL. I would like to form/ build a JSON structure

Comment: Need more inputs. So what you have tried so far??Also elaborate a little more what you want

Comment: You can do this using only sql so that the only resultset get is the json object you want. This is better as later javascript manipulation will use more memory. See: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/sqlp/rbafyjsonpublishing.htm. Please update your question adding the database schema

Answer (score 1):

Here i use one common key name as employer_id in all table result so it will easy to map all result as per employer id

```js
let employee_details =[{
    "employer_id":1,
    "roleName": "Analyst",
    "beginDate": "01/01/2000",
    "endDate": "12/31/2001",
    "status": "Active"
  },{
    "employer_id":1,
    "roleName": "Developer",
    "beginDate": "01/01/2002",
    "endDate": "01/01/2021",
    "status": "Active"
  }
]
let employee_personal_details =[{
   "employer_id":1,
   "firstName": "Jason",
   "lastName": "Washington"
}]

let employee_work_details = [{
    "employer_id":1,
    "hireDate": "01/01/2000",
    "serviceDate": "01/01/2000"
}]

let employee = employee_work_details.map(details=>{
    return {
        ...details,
        employeeDetails: employee_details.filter(_details => _details.employer_id == details.employer_id),
        name: employee_personal_details.filter( personal_details => personal_details.employer_id == details.employer_id)
    }
})
console.log({employee})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *map* and *reduce* to build an array from multiple input arrays.

We match based on some shared id, in this case employeeId.

You could make this behaviour more sophisticated by specifying a join property for each array, let's say name or date of birth.

```js
const employees = [{ id: 1, name: "Mark Ryan" }, { id: 2, name: "Joe Smith" }, { id: 3, name: "Meg Green" }];
const employeeDetails = [{ employeeId: 1, roleName: "Analyst", beginDate: "01/01/2002" }, { employeeId: 1, roleName: "Developer", beginDate: "01/01/2005"  }, { employeeId: 2, roleName: "QA", beginDate: "03/05/2015" }, { employeeId: 3, roleName: "Manager",beginDate: "11/08/2010"  }];
const contactDetails = [{ employeeId: 1, email: "mark.ryan@example.com" }, { employeeId: 2, phone: "555-009" }, { employeeId: 2, email: "joe.smith@example.com" }, { employeeId: 3, email: "meg.ryan@example.com" }];

const arraysToJoin = [ { employeeDetails } , { contactDetails } ];

const result = employees.map(employee => { 
    return arraysToJoin.reduce( (acc, obj) => {
      acc[Object.keys(obj)[0]] = Object.values(obj)[0].filter(details => acc.id === details.employeeId).map(details => {
          const { employeeId, ...rest } = details;
          return rest;
      });
      return acc;
    }, employee);
});

console.log("Result:",result);
```